# Copy constructor

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

Why the argument to a copy constructor is passed by reference?

Comment: think what would happen if it were passed by value...

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c).

Answer (score 10):

If it is passed by value it would require making a copy using a...COPY CONSTRUCTOR.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass it by value because pass-by-value implies making/passing a copy of the thing ... making a copy of the parameter passed to the copyy constructor would be recursive, cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can't pass it by value - because then you'd need a copy to create a copy!

The only other alternative would be to pass by pointer, but the syntax would require address-of, like so:

```
MyClass copy(otherclass);  // by reference
MyClass copy(&otherclass); // by pointer
```