# s copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

The idea of copy constructor really confuses me.  I don't understand why they use references and why constant references in copy constructor?

Comment: Presumably a c++ question. What does your C++ textbook have to say on the subject?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 10):

Why you use a reference: if you didn't, you'd have to create a copy of the object you want to copy. That would have to be done with a copy constructor. Insert infinite loop here.

Why a const reference: you want to guarantee that the object you're copying is not being modified.

**[Edit]** As DeadMG states in his comment, you also want the reference to be `const` so that you can create a copy of a temporary instance. E.g. suppose you have:

```
class Matrix
{
  Matrix const operator+ (Matrix const & rhs) const;
  // Code & stuff
}
```

You want the return value to be `const`, so that stupid things such as the following raise a compiler error:

```
Matrix a, b, c;
(a + b) = c;
```

Now obviously that's a silly statement, but if the return type from `operator+` wasn't `const`, it would actually be allowed. Of course, on the next line, the temporary `(a + b)` would go out of scope and you would be unable to ever use it.

However, as said before, you want to be able to create an instance with a temporary instance:

```
Matrix a, b;
Matrix c(a + b);
```

If the argument to the copy constructor wasn't `const`, that wouldn't be possible, since the return type from `operator+` is `const`.

Comment: And so that it can accept references to temporaries in existing C++.

Comment: Although note that C++0x move semantics might be outwitted by your `operator+` that returns a const temporary. If `(a+b)` is const then it can't be moved to another `Matrix`, only copied. The "as-if" rule might still save you from a costly copy, but IIRC not in all cases. In this respect, move semantics are like doing `x.swap(a+b)` instead of `x = a+b` in C++03, although with `swap` if `a+b` is `const` then the optimization doesn't compile - with move semantics if move assignment is impossible it falls back to a copy assignment.

Comment: Oops, I meant doing `(a+b).swap(x)` instead of `x = a+b`. Doing `x.swap(a+b)` isn't much use because even if non-const, `a+b` won't bind to a non-const reference. Anyway, the gist is supposed to be that even if it was before, it is no longer "obvious" that `operator+` should return a const object.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ "reference" type can simply be thought of as a constant pointer that is initialized to the value of the address of an object ... in other words a reference can never be NULL, it has to point to some object.  It therefore can also be implicitly dereferenced behind-the-scenes for you by the complier, so you do not have to worry about managing the pointer itself, as well as associated pointer syntax.

So with a copy constructor, you are basically passing a constant pointer to the object you're copying into the copy constructor function ... you're not copying the object itself.  If you did have to copy the object itself into a temporary object that is then used by the copy constructor to create a new copy, as noted previously, you'd end up with an infinite loop since what would have copied the object into the temporary object in the first place?  On the other hand, if you are just moving a pointer around, then there is no copy-constructor needed to get the object you want to copy into the copy constructor function.  Reference syntax is used rather than an actual constant pointer though because 1) a reference can't be NULL (if it was pointer-syntax, we could pass a NULL to a constant pointer), and the by-product of that means 2) a lot of things are simpler, including the syntax since the compiler can do the implicit dereferencing of the passed-in reference pointer for you, so you can use normal member-accessing syntax like `myclass.member_function()` rather than `myclass->member_function()`.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question "What is a reference?"

Comment: I was just trying to show why they use references ... In other words the way the question was asked, it seemed as though it was also asking "Why do they use references and not the objects themselves? (or for that fact, why not some other type?)".  If you understand what a reference is in the first place, then the reasoning behind the need for references becomes much clearer when they are used.