# copy-constructor related question (native c++)

Tags: c++, class, syntax, copy-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

i know that a copy constructor must have a reference as a parameter, to avoid an 'infinite number of calls' to itself. my question is - why exactly that happens, what is the logic behind it?

```
CExample(const CExample& temp)
{
   length = temp.length;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Please put more effort into asking something precise.

Comment: i mean why an infinite loop happens?

Comment: What *infinite loop* are you talking about?

Comment: an infinite loop that can happen if the argument passed to copy constr. is not a reference ---> (const CExample temp)

Comment: @Niello, that is not loop, that is recursion. The term loop is used for, well, loops: for(;;){}, while(){}, do{}while().

Comment: @Dialecticus thanx for clearing that up)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assume your argument to the copy C'tor was passed by value, the first thing the C'tor would have done, was copying the argument [that's what every function, including constructors do with by-value arguments]. in order to do so, it would have to invoke the C'tor again, from the original to the local variable... [and over and over again...] which will eventually cause an infinite loop.

Comment: "A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&,
volatile X& or const volatile X&,[...]" so anything else is not even a copy ctor...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: first word in my answer is 'assume'. the OP asks hyopthetical question, 'what if' when he asks 'what is the logic behind it'

Answer (score 2):

Copy constructors are called on some occasions in C++. One of them is when you have a function like

```
void f(CExample obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

In this case, when you make a call

```
CExample x;
f( x );
```

`CExample::CExample` gets called to construct `obj` from `x`.

In case you have the following signature

```
void f(CExample &obj)
{
     // ...
}
```

(note that `obj` is now passed by reference), the copy constructor `CExample::CExample` **does not** get called.

In the case your constructor accepts the object to be copied by value (as with the function `f` in the first example), compiler will have to call the copy constructor **first** in order to create a copy (as with the function `f`, again), but... oops, we have to call the copy constructor in order to call the copy constructor. This sounds bad, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

[See here](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/copyconstructors.html)

"It is a reference because a value parameter would require making a copy, which would invoke the copy constructor, which would make a copy of its parameter, which would invoke the copy constructor, which ... "

Or put a different way a value parameter to the constructor would have to call the constructor to copy the value in the parameter. This new constructor would need to do the same - leading to infinite recursion!