# Question about passing class as alias parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, class, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

I have the following code:

```
class Student {
private:
    int no;
    char name[14];
public:
    void display() const;
    Student(const Student& student); // Line 1
};
```

I have read that class is a reference type, so why in Line 1 of the above code declared as alias.
Is `Line 1` equivalent to: `Student(const Student student);` ?

Comment: "I have read that class is a reference type" Why are you reading a C# book instead of a [C++ book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks)?

Comment: There is no such thing as *reference types* in C++

Comment: @David: Yes there is: `const Student&` is a reference type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have read that class is a reference type

In C++, the assertion that “class is a reference type” makes no sense. You may have heard this in connection with C# but this is a completely different matter.

Consequently, the whole discussion is moot. To understand the syntax of copy constructors you first need to understand references (those *do* exist in C++) and classes in general. Grab a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1968) for beginners.

Comment: "Reference type" makes perfect sense: that's what `const Student&` is.

Comment: @Mike True. In the context of OP’s text, however, it was used in a way that clearly comes from C#’s usage – to contrast reference (classes) and value (struct) types. I’ll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First I would use

```
std::string name
```

instead of

```
char name[14]
```

and `Student(const Student student);` is NOT the same as `Student(const Student& student);`

```
Student(const Student student) //is a copy
Student(const Student& student) // is a reference to the object
```

Answer (score 2):

Classes are not reference types. You probably got that from C# or something. You have to add `&` to a type name to make it a reference. So `Student` is a student object, whereas `Student&` is a reference to a `Student` object.

Comment: Wow, my edit didn't get saved... My answer was way longer than this...

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all the same code.

Passing a parameter by reference will push the exact object on the function's argument stack. Passing one by value will push a copy.

If you declare your copy constructor without the reference, you'll get an infinite loop, as the program will try to create a copy calling the copy constructor, which in turn will try to create a copy and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Class is not a reference type. It is a **user defined type** in C++. When ever we use `&` as a part of (member) function argument(s), it means we receive a reference of the parameter(s) passed. Any modification made to the reference will actually modify the passed parameter itself. While in the other case, a copy of the object is made.

Answer (score 0):

Class is a reference type in many managed languages (like Java or C#). It is not the case however in C++. If you write `Student(const Student student);` it means you define a constructor taking one parameter of type Student *by value*. In essence copying the object into the scope of the function.

Also in C++ we call syntax like this: `Student(const Student& student);` passing by reference, not alias (in essence the same, but it may be confusing when reading up on some related subject).