# New C++ Template class Constructor that takes a type of itself as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm working on a template Class in C++ similar to the ArrayList in java (yes I know vector does the same thing, this is not a utilitarian coding project).

I figured it would be useful to have a Constructor for my ArrayList class that takes another ArrayList as an argument to seed the ArrayList. But when I try and write the constructor I get this error

```
invalid constructor; you probably meant 'ArrayList<T> (const ArrayList<T>&)'
```

Does this mean that the ArrayList has to be a constant? And why do I need the addressof operator?

I'm still learning the ropes of C++ so I'm a bit confused.

The prototypes are here:

```
    ArrayList(ArrayList<T> list);
    ArrayList(ArrayList<T> list, int size);
```

The code is here:

```
/**
 * Creates an ArrayList of type T that is twice the
 * size of the passed in ArrayList, and adds all elements
 * from the passed ArrayList<T> list, to this ArrayList.
 *
 * Runs in O(n) time, where n = the size of list.
 *
 * @param list the ArrayList to use as a seed for this ArrayList.
 */
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList<T> list) {

    array = new T[list.getSize() * 2];
    capacity = list->getSize() * 2;
    size = list->getSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < list->getSize(); i++) {

        array[i] = list->get(i);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
The below code gets no errors, while the above does.....

```
/**
 * Creates an ArrayList of type T that has a capacity equal to the passed
 * in theCapacity parameter. This ArrayList starts with the passed ArrayList.
 *
 * Note: If the passed in capacity is smaller than the size of the passed in
 *          ArrayList, then the capacity is set to twice the size of the
 *          passed ArrayList.
 *
 * @param list the ArrayList to use as a seed for this ArrayList.
 * @param theCapacity the capacity for this ArrayList.
 */
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList<T> list, int theCapacity) {

    if (theCapacity >= list->getSize()) {

        array = new T[theCapacity];
        capacity = theCapacity;
    }
    else {

        array = new T[list->getSize() * 2];
        capacity = list->getSize() * 2;
    }

    size = list->size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        array[i] = list->get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a complete, minimal example

Comment: oh shit I forgot to hit ctrl + C

Comment: You are trying to write a copy constructor, which must have a reference argument.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(const ArrayList<T>& list)
```

as your constructor signature to pass the arraylist as a `const` reference. This is the proper signature for a copy constructor. Both the implementation and calling code needn't change, unless you are modifying `list` within your ctor.

When you do `ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList<T> list)` you are creating a temporary copy of the entire ArrayList instance. (You mustn't do this for ctors since it will invoke infinite recursion, as the new copy of `list` will use the same function definition and so on).

`ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList<T>& list)` passes the list as a reference, meaning it is no longer what is often called "pass by value" and work on the exact version of the list from the calling code.

By accepting a const reference in a function, you are saying that the function will not modify the contents of the reference (i.e. not do any modifying operations on it : it will be constrained to only `const` accesses). You should read about `const`, references and copy constructors before going further.

**Update:**

For pass by value or reference, you can access members via the `obj.member` syntax. If you were passing a pointer like `ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList<T>* list)`, you would have to use `list->member` syntax or `(*list).member` syntax, not to mention checking if list is `0`/`nullptr` first (you can't dereference null pointers).

You are mixing syntax for pointers and syntax for value/references. convert all of your `list->x` into `list.x` since you aren't passing the `list` argument using pointers.

See this for different passing behaviours: http://ideone.com/3c5mJ

Comment: When I switch to that though i get this error on the contents of the constructor

base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const ArrayList<int>'

if i'm using the addressof how can it be a non pointer type?! :?

Comment: @Ethan now that its a reference, you can use `obj.member` syntax just as you would in pass by value. This is how references work in C++.

Comment: that means that you have some problem with implementation of your functions. You need to give us more details how you implement the class and use it.

Comment: I have test code for all of my functions and they function fine in there so I don't think the problem lies with my functions.

Also it's very odd....in one of the constructors, I already had the -> operator and I get no errors on it (but if I switch to the simple obj.memberFunction() syntax, I get an error:

    Invalid arguments '
    Candidates are:
    int getSize()
    '

Whilst on the other constructor I get the non pointer type error with the -> operator, and with the .functionMember() syntax I get the same error as above....I'm so lost

Answer (score 2):

"const" is used because it is reference on some object, which you will not change.
reference is used because this is copy constructor and default syntax suppose reference.

But the most important: You can define and use this constructor in the Exactly Same way as the one you trying to write.