# C++: why constructor "A(A a) {}" is illegal?

Tags: c++, constructor

I met a quiz saying that the code below is ill-formed because "It is illegal to have a constructor whose first and only non-default argument is a value parameter for the class type."

I couldn't understand that. Why things like `A(A a) : val (a.val) {}` is ruled as illegal? why such a line in the standard? Is it because this will lead to ambiguity with copy constructor?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A() : val() {}
  A(int v) : val(v) {}
  A(A a) : val(a.val) {} 

  int val;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A a1(5);
  A a2(a1);

  std::cout << a1.val + a2.val << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use a header file?

Comment: @CommuSoft it's not related to header file.

Comment: Copy constructors cannot pass their argument by-value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A(A a) : val(a.val) {}` will cause an infinite recursion because constructor arguments are being copied by value (invoking copy constructor and again the copy constructor and ...)

Comment: so it's not possible to have both `A(A &a) : val(a.val) {}` and `A(A a) : val(a.val) {} `? is it because it's not able to differentiate them during function matching?

Comment: Yes, you can not have both.

Answer (score 3):

A copy constructor is called when an object is passed by value. Copy constructor itself is a function. So if we pass argument by value in a copy constructor, a call to copy constructor would be made to call copy constructor which becomes a **non-terminating chain of calls**. Therefore compiler doesn’t allow parameters to be pass by value

Its already discussed on this SO post
[Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Everything changes with const:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A () : _a(0) {}
    A (int a) : _a(a) {}
    A (const A& a) : _a(a._a) {}
    int _a;
};

int main()
{
    A a(5);
    A b(10);
    A c(a);

    std::cout << a._a + b._a + c._a << std::endl; // 20
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't quite get what you mean.....