# Why It is illegal to copy an object if a member of the class is a reference?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

I met a quiz saying that the code in line 18 below is ill-formed because "It is ill-formed to use an implicitly defined assignment operator when one of the members that will need to be copied is a reference. "

I couldn't understand that. Why reference could not be copied? Why Line 16 is legal? Line 16 is quite similar to line 18, a copy constructor still need to do the copy, right?

```
1 #include <iostream>
2
3 struct A
4 {
5   A(int& var) : r(var) {}
6
7   int &r;
8 };
9
10 int main(int argc, char** argv)
11 {
12   int x = 23;
13
14   A a1(x);
15
16   A a2 = a1;
17
18   a2 = a1;
19
20   return 0;
21 }
```

Comment: [Are you going to post the whole quiz?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792560/c-why-constructor-aa-a-is-illegal)

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense. grats on the 97.4% test btw.

Comment: Illegal to *assign*, not to *copy*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is illegal in `C++` to reassign to a reference.

```
int &a = some_int;
a = some_other_int; // value copied not reference
a = some_int; // value copied not reference
```

When you use assignation operator (generated by compiler), it blindly does the copy of objects and thus try to reassign to your reference and hence is invalid.

When you say `a2 = a1;`, compiler would try to reassign `a1.r` to `a2.r` making it fail at compile time because it is ill-formation.

You can think of a reference as an `automatically dereferenced constant pointer`. So the line `a2 = a1;` will remain ill-formatted for the same reason as for the class below.

```
struct A
{
  A(int *var) : p(var) {}
  int * const p;
};
```

Comment: It's illegal to rebind a reference. There isn't even syntax for it. The statement you labeled as illegal, however, is not.

Comment: You dropped the erroneous comment, but your reasoning is still incorrect, because `a1.r = a2.r` would not be ill-formed. Nor would an initialization of one reference from another be ill-formed, as it would simply bind the second reference to the first reference's referent.

Comment: i tried `int some_int = 3; int some_other_int = 5; int &a = some_int;
some_int = 4; a = some_other_int; some_other_int = 6;` it works

Comment: @athos define "works". When your commented  snippet completes, `some_int` will be `5`, `some_other_int` will be `6`, and `a` *still* references `some_int` (which is as already mentioned: `5`).

Answer (score 6):

Line 16 uses a copy constructor, line 18 uses the assignment operator `operator=`. Two different functions with different restrictions.

Because a reference can't be rebound, the compiler can't generate an implicit assignment operator that makes any sense. Thus it refuses to do so, and generates an error.

A copy constructor is generating the object for the first time, so it can bind that reference the same way you did in your own constructor.

Answer (score 3):

A class with a reference member has no default-provided copy/move assignment operators. References cannot be rebound to reference a different variable once binding is established. In short, the copy constructor is making that initial establishment, while the default assignment operator would be trying to *change* it after-binding.

The standard therefore calls this case out for both default copy and move assignment operators.

> **C++11 § 12.8p23**
>
> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has:

- a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding assignment operator and X is a union-like class, or
- a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
- **a non-static data member of reference type**, or
- a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
- a direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to B’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
- for the move assignment operator, a non-static data member or direct base class with a type that does not have a move assignment operator and is not trivially copyable, or any direct or indirect virtual base class.

You can certainly write *your own* overload.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int& var) : r(var) {}

    int &r;

    A& operator=(const A& obj)
    {
        r = obj.r; // value copied, reference-binding remains the same
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int x = 42;
    int y = 43;

    A a1(x);
    A a2(y);

    A a3 = a1; // legal. default copy-ctor invoked
    a3 = a2;   // legal. user-defined copy-assignment invoked

    std::cout << x << ',' << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
43,43
```

But this will not (and cannot) rebind the reference. The overload provided here changes the *referenced* data; not the references themselves. Such a distinction is important.

Hope this helps.