# what if C++ class contains both const reference and non-const reference copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, const-reference

**snippet 1:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C(){}
    C(const C& c){
        cout<<"const copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    C c1;
    C c2 = c1;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**: const copy constructor called

---

snippet 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C(){}
    C(const C& c){
        cout<<"const copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    C(C& c){
        cout<<"non-const copy constructor called.\t "<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    C c1;
    C c2 = c1;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**: non-const copy constructor called

---

snippet 3:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C(){}
    C(const C& c){
        cout<<"const copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    C(C c){
        cout<<"non-const copy constructor called.\t "<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    C c1;
    C c2 = c1;
    return 0;
}
```

**output**: error: copy constructor must pass its first argument by reference

---

I am so confused about:

1. for snippet 2, why the non-const copy constructor here is valid? why non-const copy constructor was called, rather than the const one.
2. for snippet 3, I know that copy constructor must use const reference to avoid infinite recursion. But Here class C has got `C(const C& c)`, `C(C c)` won't cause infinite recursion, why it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Snippet 1**: One standard copy constructor with `const T&`. Happy world.

**Snippet 2**:

What you have effectively done is overloaded the copy constructor - one that takes a reference `T&` and the other that takes a constant reference `const T&`.

Please note: Any constructor for a class T that has one mandatory argument of type `T &` or `const T &` (it may also have further, defaulted arguments) is a copy constructor.

So, for the compiler, it all just boils down to finding the **Best Fit** for overload resolution and it is done as:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence S2 if:
>
> - ....
> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers,
>     and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more
>     cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1
>     refers.

So writing

```
C c1;
C c2 = c1;
```

will call the non-const copy constructor since it is a better match, but,

writing,

```
const C c1;
C c2 = c1;
```

will call the const copy constructor (you can check) since now the copy constructor with const is the only viable match.

Snippet 3 is just plain wrong for the compiler.

```
C(C c){
        cout<<"non-const copy constructor called.\t "<<endl;
    }
```

You can't have a method with a signature `C(C c)`. The compiler thinks that you are trying to write a copy constructor and missed writing the `&` and hence reports the error. Remove it and it works fine.

@Unless you have a very good reason, **never ever use `C(C& c)` for your copy constructor. Don't skip `const`** because mutating the object from which you are making a copy doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What is surprising for me is that `C c2=static_cast<const C>(c1);` still calls the non-const version.

Comment: @Paulo1205 Try `static_cast<const C&>(c1)`.

Comment: "since now the copy constructor with const is a better match" It's the only viable match.

Answer (score 3):

> for snippet 2, why the non-const copy constructor here is valid? why non-const copy constructor was called, rather than the const one.

Consider your code for this question, but with the change below with the comment `// (*)`:

```
int main(){
    const C c1; // (*) <- See change here
    C c2 = c1;
    return 0;
}
```

This calls the `const` copy ctor version. It really has nothing to do with the function happening to be a constructor - if a function has two overloads, one taking a reference, and one a `const` reference, then non-const objects will be called with the first, and `const` objects with the second.

> for snippet 3, I know that copy constructor must use const reference to avoid infinite recursion. But Here class C has got C(const C& c), C(C c) won't cause infinite recursion, why it still doesn't work?

Consider the following code, and note that there is no invocation going on (the content of `main` is pretty much erased).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C(){}
    C(const C& c){
        cout<<"const copy constructor called"<<endl;
    }
    C(C c){
        cout<<"non-const copy constructor called.\t "<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
// Note that nothing is creating C instances at all.
return 0;
}
```

This results in the exact same error - the compiler simply refuses to compile a class with this interface, regardless of whether something is attempting to call it or not.

Quoting from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c) "it's forbidden by the standard in §12.8/3:

> A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its first parameter is of type (optionally cv- qualified) X and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

"