# why do we have to reference an object in the object's constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

So I was doing an hacker Rank problem in which I was learning about constructor polymorphism
so there's this class Box with three member variables l , b and h.
and it has three constructors
`Box(): l(0), b(0), h(0){}`
`Box(int a , int x , int c): l(a), b(x), h(c){}`
but then you have this copy constructor
`Box(Box &B)`
here I have a question as to why do I need to reference the `Box B` in the parameter and not just simply pass it as a copy i.e. `Box(Box B)`

I get the error that : in a copy constructor the first parameter needs to be passed as a reference but again it does not make a difference right as finally all we are doing is copying the values of another object into our current object .I don't understand the reason to pass it as a reference

Comment: hacker rank isnt the place to learn the basics. Try here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+book and here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

Comment: How do you expect the object `B` to be initialised if it is passed by value?

Comment: A proper copy constructor has a const reference parameter: `Box(const Box &b)`. Moreover, simple classes like your `Box` don't need a custom copy constructor at all, if you remove it it will get generated automatically.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai that's what OP is asking

Comment: When you pass the object by value, it needs to be *copied*. Using the copy-constructor. So how would that work for the copy-constructor, if it needs to be called to create the copy, and that in turn needs to call the copy-constructor for the argument to be copied, which needs the copy-constructor to be called to copy the object... And so on in infinity.

Comment: Because **otherwise you'll have infinite recursion**. See [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude technically `Box::Box(Box)` *isn't* [a copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I was prompting them to think about the initialisation of the parameter, not the source nor the object under construction

Comment: @Caleth oooh sorry, I was a bit slow, now I get it